# How to create an API Key System for a mobile app

Tags: php, objective-c, database, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm programming an online database based app, but at least the authentification is missing!
A friend of mine says I should use oauth, but I don't understand, why this is secure!
If there is a hacker, he would see this key at all and could get in with his own request, wouldn't he?

Does anybody has an example, why this isn't the case?

And maybe some code tutorial how to implement this with php and objective-c?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The insecurity is that you are trusting the site you are authentication against to have good security policies. I don't trust that for my usage, it may be fine for you. You need to define what you are securing and the value to both you and your users.

So, use oath if it meets you security needs. It it doesn't then hire a security domain expert to create your custom authentication.